# How to use apollo-link-http with apollo-upload-client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, graphql, apollo

Im trying to figure out how to use [apollo-link-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-link-http) with [apollo-upload-client](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client).

Both create a terminating link, but how could I use those 2 together? In my index.js I have like this, but it wont work because both links are terminating =>

```
const uploadLink = createUploadLink({ uri: process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_URL });

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_URL });

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([ authLink, logoutLink, stateLink, uploadLink, httpLink ]),
    cache,
});
```

Any help? I have not much experience with Apollo/Graphql, but I would like to use the file upload component.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You do not need the http link if you use `apollo-upload-client` with version higher than 6.

You can try like this:

```
const uploadLink = createUploadLink({ uri: process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_URL });

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([ authLink, logoutLink, stateLink, uploadLink ]),
    cache,
});
```

Comment: This is correct. The final problem however was that I had too old react-scripts package. Updated to 1.1.2 and now working.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was forgetting to create an uploadLink.

Comment: How do you pass http link options to it (like useGETForQueries)?